# Setting a fixed amount of y Axis Lines to display on Apache ECharts

Tags: bar-chart, linechart, echarts, yaxis

I'm trying to show only a certain amount of yAxis Lines in my `Apache ECharts` Chart.
I tried the following:

```
yAxis: [
{
 type: 'value',
 min:0,
 max:6000
}
],
yAxis: [
{
 type: 'value',
 scale:true,
 splitNumber:4,
}
],
```

I need to dislpay it like this:

[image: How it should look like]

For your information: I need this to work on every Chart-Type, Line Chart, Bar Chart etc.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

So, as I have not got any answer. I wanted to share with anyone who might need it in the future, how I solved it.
I looked and got the highest number of the data for the current Chart and looked if it is near 1000 I rounded it up to 1000, if it is over 1000 I rounded it up to the nearest 200.
For example a number 1059 becomes => 1200 or the number 1215 becomes 1400.
Than simply get this Number and divide it by 4(to have 4 Lines).
And give this number to the yAxis max. For the min set 0.

Comment: what's the value of yAxis.splitNumber?